# parcing a struct as a input in a consructor of other class in c++

Tags: c++

I have two different header file and one main file.

**headerfile 1 :**  `env.h`

```
#include <math.h>

struct env
{
  env(int a, int b)
  {
      /*data*/
  }

  auto add(int a, int b)
  {
      return a+b;
  }
};
```

**headerfile 2 :** `Myclass.h`

```
#include <random>

class myclass
{

  static auto dot(int a, int b, env& E) -> int;

}

myclass::dot(int a, int b, env& E) -> int
{
  int temp = E.add(a,b);
  return temp;
}
```

**main file :** `main.cpp`

```
#include <env.h>

int main(){

  int a = 5;
  int b = 6;

  env E(a, b);

  int c = myclass::dot(a, b, E)

  return 0;
}
```

What i would like to do is to parse the class definition(`env E`) in main file into the construction(`myclass::dot()`) of other class(`myclass`). But i am getting the error as "declaration is incompatible with myclass::dot". What i think is that `Myclass.h` does not know the value type of struct `env`. So how to define the class in `Myclass.h`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about this: https://onlinegdb.com/ByS9zYvl_

Comment: @JerryJeremiah If i include env.h in Myclass.h then i am getting error in main.cpp stating that : `no suitable user-defined conversion from "env" to "env" exists`

Comment: First include `env.h` then `Myclass.h` in `main.cpp`, this->Problem is Solved. Thanks!

Comment: @даршан I still don't expect it to work because `dot` in `myclass` is a private static member function.

Comment: Include `env.h` in `Myclass.h`, then in `Myclass.h`, replace `env` with `struct env`

Comment: @D-RAJ Sorry, `dot` constructor has to be public. Please refer [this](https://www.onlinegdb.com/ByS9zYvl_).